# cannot enter 2 character type variables java

Tags: java, character

```
import java.io.*;

public class character 
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("enter two characters");
        char a=(char)br.read();
        char b=(char)br.read();
        System.out.println("1."+a);
        System.out.println("2."+b);
    }
}
```

This is my code and for some reason it refuses to enter the second character and directly jumps to the  outputting. Can someone please help?

Comment: Hello Chisha! You would like to enter a character press ENTER and then input a second character and press ENTER? And then see the result?

Answer (score 2):

This is because `br.read()` is used twice.
You are basically reading two characters from console.

So when you press enter `(which terminates read())` after entering first character lets say `a` you'll get following output:

```
a='a';
b=ENTER KEY
```

If you enter anything other than enter it would take that character in `b`.

Comment: but she is  invoking the `read()` method twice !! Can you explain that too

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be reading the enter key into your 2nd char but don't quote me on that. You could try:

```
char a=(char)br.readLine().charAt(0);
char b=(char)br.readLine().charAt(0);
```

Yes.. it's assigning the value (13) of the enter key to char b:

If you do this you'll see it:

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("enter two characters");
char a=(char)br.read();
char b=(char)br.read();
int c = (int)b;
System.out.println("1."+a);
System.out.println("2."+c);
```

**Outputs:**

enter two characters

a

1.a

2.13

http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/carriage-return-ascii-code-13.html

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote will get the first two characters from the console. This includes whitespace or newline characters. That means if you type `a b` the first character will be `a` and the second will be a space.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class character {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("enter two characters");
    char a = (char) br.read();
    char b = (char) br.read();
    int c=(int)b;
    System.out.println("1." + a);
    System.out.println("2." + c);
}
```

Input

> enter two characters
>   1

So when you press enter which terminates read() and you'll get following output:

> 1.1
>   2.10

Here 10 comes from ASCII value of Line feed

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("enter two characters");
    int count = 0;
    char[] characters = new char[2];
    while (count < 2) {
        String line = br.readLine();
        characters[count] = line.charAt(0);
        count ++;
    }
    System.out.println(characters[0]);
    System.out.println(characters[1]);
```

This code will read the ENTER key and skip to the next line. This way you can type in two characters separated by ENTER key.